# On MacOS, how can I stop the OS trying to update the *deleted* iTunes?

Tags: macos, mac, automatic-update, itunes-10

On my Mac OS 10.5.8 I've deleted iTunes (by dragging it from Applications to trash and then emptying the bin. However, approximately once a week Mac OS suggests installing an update for it. Why and how to stop it?

Comment: You cannot remove iTunes from OS X, at least not in a supported manner.

Comment: @RandolphWest: Sounds just like Internet Explorer in Windows ;) However OSX didn't complain about me deleting iTunes. So I cannot launch it, but it wants to be updated. Very user-friendly :) Is it possible to exclude it from auto-updates may be? I don't mind it wasting my disk space too much. But it's continuously suggesting downloading over 150 Mb of update. This is really annoying.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to exclude it. As I said, it's not supported to remove it at all, under OS X. OSXdaily.com has ways to get rid of it (using `sudo rm -rf /Applications/iTunes`), but I'm pretty sure updates will keep showing up.

Answer (score 2):

When in the software update application select the iTunes update that is being offered to you and press delete (keyboard) or go to the update menu in the toolbar and select 'Ignore this update'.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the application (and its hidden Package Contents) with an uninstaller for Mac. I suggest [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/)

It sounds like you did not completely remove iTunes when you deleted it.